# Azure Configure Visual Studio with Management Certificate

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have an active Azure Subscription. I would like one of my team mates to connect to my subscription from visual studio. However, I don't want to share my credentials with my developer. Is there an alternate on how to get that done? Probably by providing them some Management Certificate? Could you please provide me any reference link where I can get more details on how to configure the same?
I have researched quite a bit on that but of now luck!

Thanks,
Prawin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Azure [`Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/), things have actually simplified quite a bit and give you great deal of control over who can do what in your Azure Subscription.

What you do is add this user to your Azure Subscription. Once you add this user, you can assign some roles to that user. My recommendation would be to start with bare minimum role (Reader) on the resources they need. It's actually pretty simple and straightforward to assign roles to users using Azure Portal.

You can also download a publish settings file associated with your Azure Subscription using https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index link. Your team member can import the publish settings file and start managing your Azure Subscription (Classic resources only).